# Finding regular expressions on files takes a long time

Tags: regex, vbscript, readfile, scom

I'm developing a VBS script for finding 3 cases of regular expressions contained into files. I've already my own script that works fine finding but it takes a long time in execution.

The 3 cases of regular expresions are:

```
Case 1
    Begin pattern:

          ^[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2} +[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2} +[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+ +pdm_mail_nxd +[0-9]+ +SIGNIFICANT +pdm_mail_nxd\.c +[0-9]+ +Mail Stats: Received\([0-9]+\) Sent\(0\) In Queue\([1-9][0-9]*\) In Work\([0-9]+\) Max Sessions\([0-9]+\) Errors\([0-9]+\) Invalid Msgs\([0-9]+\) Tracing\((Yes|No)\)$

     End patern:
          ^[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2} +[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2} +[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+ +pdm_mail_nxd +[0-9]+ +SIGNIFICANT +pdm_mail_nxd\.c +[0-9]+ +Mail Stats: Received\([0-9]+\) Sent\([1-9][0-9]*\) In Queue\([0-9]+\) In Work\([0-9]+\) Max Sessions\([0-9]+\) Errors\([0-9]+\) Invalid Msgs\([0-9]+\) Tracing\((Yes|No)\)$


Case 2
     Begin pattern:
          ^[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2} +[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2} +[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+ +slump_nxd +[0-9]+ +SIGNIFICANT +socket_port\.c +[0-9]+ +Unable to write to \(pdm_mail_nxd\) for [1-9][0-9]* seconds\.
     End pattern (1):
          ^[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2} +[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2} +[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+ +slump_nxd +[0-9]+ +SIGNIFICANT +socket_port\.c +[0-9]+ +Successful write to \(pdm_mail_nxd\) occurred\. Error cleared after [0-9]+ seconds\.
     End pattern (2):
          ^[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2} +[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2} +[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+ +pdm_mail_nxd +[0-9]+ +SIGNIFICANT +pdm_mail_nxd\.c +[0-9]+ +STARTUP of pdm_mail_nxd

Case 3
     Begin pattern:
          ^[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2} +[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2} +[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+ +slump_nxd +[0-9]+ +SIGNIFICANT +socket_port\.c +[0-9]+ +Too long in error state - dropping connection to SOCKET_PORT\(0x[0-9A-F]+\) description = socket port port_name = pdm_mail_nxd
     End pattern:
          ^[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2} +[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2} +[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+ +pdm_mail_nxd +[0-9]+ +SIGNIFICANT +pdm_mail_nxd\.c +[0-9]+ +STARTUP of pdm_mail_nxd
```

... And this is my script:

```
Dim oAPI, oBag
Dim objFso, objFile, objTextFile, obj_Carpeta
Dim str_Path, strFile, stdlog, fileName, text, i, j, LineCount, sline, strlog, fLines
Dim strMatch_Start1, strMatch_End1, strMatch_Start2, strMatch_End2A, strMatch_End2B, strMatch_Start3, strMatch_End3
Dim exp_Start1, exp_Start2, exp_Start3, exp_End1, exp_End2A, exp_End2B, exp_End3
Dim case1, case2, case3

str_Path = "E:\CA\Service Desk Manager\log2"

'CASE 1
exp_Start1 = "^[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2} +[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2} +[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+ +pdm_mail_nxd +[0-9]+ +SIGNIFICANT +pdm_mail_nxd\.c +[0-9]+ +Mail Stats: Received\([0-9]+\) Sent\(0\) In Queue\([1-9][0-9]*\) In Work\([0-9]+\) Max Sessions\([0-9]+\) Errors\([0-9]+\) Invalid Msgs\([0-9]+\) Tracing\((Yes|No)\)$"
exp_End1   = "^[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2} +[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2} +[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+ +pdm_mail_nxd +[0-9]+ +SIGNIFICANT +pdm_mail_nxd\.c +[0-9]+ +Mail Stats: Received\([0-9]+\) Sent\([1-9][0-9]*\) In Queue\([0-9]+\) In Work\([0-9]+\) Max Sessions\([0-9]+\) Errors\([0-9]+\) Invalid Msgs\([0-9]+\) Tracing\((Yes|No)\)$"
'CASE 2
exp_Start2 = "^[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2} +[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2} +[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+ +slump_nxd +[0-9]+ +SIGNIFICANT +socket_port\.c +[0-9]+ +Unable to write to \(pdm_mail_nxd\) for [1-9][0-9]* seconds\."
exp_End2A  = "^[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2} +[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2} +[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+ +slump_nxd +[0-9]+ +SIGNIFICANT +socket_port\.c +[0-9]+ +Successful write to \(pdm_mail_nxd\) occurred\. Error cleared after [0-9]+ seconds\." 
exp_End2B  = "^[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2} +[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2} +[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+ +pdm_mail_nxd +[0-9]+ +SIGNIFICANT +pdm_mail_nxd\.c +[0-9]+ +STARTUP of pdm_mail_nxd"
'CASE 3
exp_Start3 = "^[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2} +[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2} +[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+ +slump_nxd +[0-9]+ +SIGNIFICANT +socket_port\.c +[0-9]+ +Too long in error state - dropping connection to SOCKET_PORT\(0x[0-9A-F]+\) description = socket port port_name = pdm_mail_nxd"
exp_End3   = "^[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2} +[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2} +[a-zA-Z0-9_\.]+ +pdm_mail_nxd +[0-9]+ +SIGNIFICANT +pdm_mail_nxd\.c +[0-9]+ +STARTUP of pdm_mail_nxd"

Set oAPI = CreateObject("MOM.ScriptAPI")
Set oBag = oAPI.CreatePropertyBag()

Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set obj_Carpeta = objFso.GetFolder(str_Path)

'Check valid path
If not objFso.FolderExists(str_Path) Then
    WScript.Echo "Error: " & str_Path & " -- not found."
    'Call oAPI.LogScriptEvent("mail_queue SDM",9551,0, "Process pdm_mail_nxd: path not found" )
    Set objFso = Nothing
    WScript.Quit 2
End If

'Call oAPI.LogScriptEvent("mail_queue SDM",9552,0, "init monitor" )

 For i = 0 to 8 
    For Each objFile In obj_Carpeta.Files
        'Check if it has files    
        stdlog = "stdlog." &i
        fileName = objFile.Name
        case1 = "False" 
        case2 = "False"
        case3 = "False"
        WScript.echo fileName
        WScript.echo stdlog
        If fileName = stdlog Then
            'Have file
            text = "" 
            i = i+1 
            strFile = str_Path & "\" & fileName
            WScript.echo strFile
            'Set objTextFile = objFile.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading)   
            text = objFile.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading).ReadAll
            WScript.echo "Reading File ..."
            'Split by lines, put into an array
            fLines = Split(text,vbCrLf)
            'Use UBound to count the lines
            LineCount = UBound(fLines)
            Set objFile = Nothing 'Cleanup
            WScript.echo "File read...   " & LineCount  & " lines" & vbCrLf


            If (InStr(1,text,"pdm_mail_nxd") > 0) Then
                'exp_Start1, exp_End1, exp_End2B, exp_End3
                WScript.echo "WORD pdm_mail_nxd FOUND!!" 
                For j = 0 to LineCount
                    sline = fLines(j)

                    'Match expression
                    strMatch_Start1 = TestRegExp (exp_Start1 , sline)
                    strMatch_End1 = TestRegExp (exp_End1 , sline)
                    'strMatch_End2B = TestRegExp (exp_End2B , sline)
                    'strMatch_End3 = TestRegExp (exp_End3 , sline)

                    If strMatch_Start1  = "True" Then

                        WScript.echo "------>   CASe 1 open"    
                        case1 = "True"      
                        strlog = sline
                        WScript.echo strlog
                        'j = j+1
                    Else

                        If strMatch_End1  = "True" Then 
                            case1 = "False" 
                        End If
                        case2 = "False"
                        case3 = "False"
                    End If
                Next
            End If

            If (InStr(1,text,"slump_nxd") > 0) Then
                'strMatch_Start2, strMatch_End2A, exp_Start3
                WScript.echo "WORD pdm_mail_nxd FOUND!!"    & vbCrLf
                For j = 0 to LineCount
                    sline = fLines(j)   
                    'Match expression
                    strMatch_Start2 = TestRegExp (exp_Start2 , sline)
                    strMatch_End2A = TestRegExp (exp_End2A , sline)
                    strMatch_Start3 = TestRegExp (exp_Start3 , sline)
                    If strMatch_Start2  = "True" Then

                        WScript.echo "-----> CASe 2 open"   
                        case2 = "True"
                        strlog = sline
                        WScript.echo strlog                 
                        'j = j+1
                    ElseIf strMatch_Start3  = "True" Then

                        WScript.echo "----> CASe 3 open"    
                        case3 = "True"                      
                        strlog = sline
                        WScript.echo strlog
                        'j = j+1
                    Else

                        case1 = "False" 
                        'case2 = "False"
                        'case3 = "False"
                    End If
                Next
            End If      
        End if
        WScript.echo "***************"
    Next
Next

If ((case1 = "True") or (case2 = "True") or (case3 = "True")) Then
    Call oAPI.LogScriptEvent("mail_queue SDM",9552,0, "DELAY -->  " & StdlogValue )
    Call oBag.AddValue("Status","Demora en envio de correo")
    Call oBag.AddValue("StdlogValue",strlog)
Else
    Call oAPI.LogScriptEvent("mail_queue SDM",9552,0, "NO DELAY")
    Call oBag.AddValue("Status","Ok")
End If

Function TestRegExp (myPattern , myString)
   Dim objRegExp, objMatch, colMatches, RetStr

   ' Create a regular expression object
   Set objRegExp = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")  
   objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True ' Set Case Insensitivity
   objRegExp.Global = True 'Set global applicability
   'Set the pattern by using the Pattern property
   objRegExp.Pattern = myPattern

   'Test whether the String can be compared
    If objRegExp.Test(myString) = True Then
       'Get the matches
        Set colMatches = objRegExp.Execute(myString)  ' Execute search
        For Each objMatch In colMatches   ' Iterate Matches collection
          RetStr = RetStr & objMatch.Value 
        Next
        If IsNull(RetStr) then
            RetStr = "False"
        Else
            RetStr = "True"
        End if
   Else
    ' String Matching Failed
     RetStr = "False"
   End If
   TestRegExp = RetStr

End Function    

'Call oAPI.LogScriptEvent("mail_queue SDM",9552,0, "End monitor" )
oAPI.Return(oBag)

'Cleanup objects 
Set objFSO = Nothing 
Set objFile = Nothing 
Set strlog = Nothing
WScript.Quit()
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Any solution or suggestion to make it faster?

Comment: It's not quite clear to me what condition(s) you want to detect.

Comment: I want to detect any line contained into the files that matches with the regular expressions betwen begin expression and end expressions above posted. My script is already able to find them but very very slow :(. Probably wrong structure or unnecessary loops...?

Comment: Funny that you would offer a bounty for this question when you never responded to the answer you already got.

Comment: Sorry about that @AnsgarWiechers but I was quite busy with other tasks and offered a bounty to get attention in order to have more than one reply. I was able to implement the script with the structure you suggested. Same result....maybe up to 1minute faster, but insufficient time decrease :(

Comment: Anyway...yours is the only reply that I got. Reputation is yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the performance issues is probably that you're parsing each file several times. The array handling and multiple regexp executions probably don't help either. Try something like this:

```
re_start = "..."
re_end   = "..."

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = re_start & "\r\n([\s\S]*?)" & re_end
re.Global  = True

For Each f In objFso.GetFolder(str_Path).Files
  txt = f.OpenAsTextStream.ReadAll
  For Each m In re.Execute(txt)
    WScript.Echo m.SubMatches(0)
  Next
Next
```

In this case the expressions `re_start` and `re_end` must not begin/end with `^` and `$`, and all groups in them must be made non-capturing groups (`(?:...)` instead of `(...)`), e.g.:

```
"[0-9]{2}/... Tracing\((?:Yes|No)\)"
```

instead of

```
"^[0-9]{2}/... Tracing\((Yes|No)\)$"
```

Comment: Thanks @Ansgar Wiechers I will try using that structure and let you know the results.